# exercise_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ArrayModifier (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on ruby loops within classes and I can't seem to get past this name error. I apologize if this question is elsewhere but what I found isn't very specific to my problem. Heres the code:

```
class StringModifier
    attr_accessor :array

    def initialize(array)
        @array = array
    end

    def exclaim
        array.each do |element|
            array
            "#{element}!"
        end
    end
 end
```

Returns the following error:

```
exercise_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ArrayModifier (NameError)
```

Rspec:

```
describe ArrayModifier do
  before do 
    @array = ["Roxanne", "Put on the red light", "Roxanne", "Put on the red light"]
  end

  describe '#exclaim' do
    it "adds an exclamation mark to each element" do
      exclaimed = ArrayModifier.new(@array).exclaim
      expect(exclaimed).to eq(["Roxanne!", "Put on the red light!", "Roxanne!", "Put on the red light!"])
    end

    it "doesn't modify the original array" do
      original = @array.dup
      exclaimed = ArrayModifier.new(@array).exclaim
      expect(@array).to eq(original)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I just tested the above code. It's working without any syntax error.

Comment: It looks like you've called your class `StringModifier` instead of `ArrayModifier` .. but that said you aren't trying to create an instance of the class in the code you quoted so the error will be elsewhere in the file. What is the rest of your code?

Comment: Show us the _exercise_spec.rb_

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you so much. Yeah another student in my program suggested maybe its that I need to call StringModifier instead of ArrayModifier but alas, regardless I still get the same error.

Comment: are you using rails ? or plain ruby ?, if you're using plain ruby and you have your class in a different file, then you just need to require it in the spec file.

Comment: Just plain old ruby but I'm not on a local environment, it's on bloc.io's platform.

Comment: There's just the file `exercise_spec.rb` ?  Is there also an `exercise.rb` ?  If so, make the first line in `exercise_spec.rb`  the following:  `require "./exercidse.rb"`